# Discrete Math Verify that $f\notin O(g)$ and $g\notin O(f)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

> 6. Let $f,g:\mathbb Z^+\to\mathbb R$ be defined as follows:
>
>    $$f(n)=\begin{cases}n,&\text{for }n\text{ odd}\\1,&\text{for }n\text{ even}\end{cases}\qquad g(n)=\begin{cases}1,&\text{for }n\text{ odd}\\n,&\text{for }n\text{ even}\end{cases}$$
>
>    Verify that $f\notin O(g)$ and $g\notin O(f)$.

Comment: yes, the definition is important to the solution

Comment: I haven't tried anything I am completely lost here and no I do not know what that means

Comment: @user85542 If you issue is that you don't know what the notation means, I would advise you to learn it / understand it first.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $f\in O(g)$ then there is some constant $c$ and natural number $N$ such that for all $n>N$ $f(n)\leq cg(n)$. Pick an odd number greater than $c$ and $N$, then
$$
f(n)=n>c=cg(n)$$

Which contradicts that our choice of $c$ and $N$. You can use the same argument for the other direction by picking an even number.

Answer (score 0):

The two parts of the problem are almost identical; I’ll do the first part and leave the second for you.

In order to show that $f$ is not $O(g)$, you must show that no matter how large you choose the integer $n_0$ and the positive constant $c$, it **not** true that $|f(n)|\le c|g(n)|$ for every $n\ge n_0$. In other words, it is **not** true that for every $n\ge n_0$.

$$n\le c\cdot1\quad\text{if}\quad n\text{ is odd}\tag{1}$$

and

$$1\le c\cdot n\quad\text{if}\quad n\text{ is even}\;.\tag{2}$$

Now $(2)$ clearly **is** true for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ provided that we choose $c\ge 1$, so it must be $(1)$ that fails. And sure enough, no matter what $c>0$ and $n_0\in\Bbb Z^+$ you choose, you can violate $(1)$ for some integer $n\ge n_0$ simply by taking $n$ to be any odd integer larger than $\max\{n_0,c\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $f \in O(g)$ iff there exists $M > 0$ and $x_0 \in \bf{Z}^+$ such that

$$|f(x)| \le M|g(x)|$$

for all $x > x_0$.  You are asked to prove the negation of this which is: For every $M > 0$ and $x_0 \in \bf{Z}^+$,  there exists an integer $x > x_0$ such that

$$|f(x)| > M|g(x)|$$

So let $M > 0$ and $x_0 \in \bf{Z}^+$.  Choose an odd $x \in \bf{Z}^+$ such that $x > \max{(M, x_0)}$.  Then,

$$|f(x)| = |x| > M = M|g(x)|$$

An identical argument shows $g \notin O(f)$.